# Jupyter Notebook scanpy import fails

Tags: python, scanpy

When I import scanpy using the command **import scanpy as sc** the kernel dies and restarts and never imports scanpy. it used to work but now it doesnt. Similar proble in Google Colab.
Any fixes for this?

pip install scanpy
import scanpy as sc

Comment: It sounds like a memory issue you are describing. I'm not seeing that though. I've neen using https://github.com/imperial-genomics-facility/scanpy-notebook-image  by clicking on '`launch binder`' badge there. Maybe using that you can compare versions because maybe the newer version has the issue. I'm seeing version 1.7.2 in use where I use it without issue.